# Need a query where if 2 condition is satisfying on 2 different date it should not show in output

Tags: sql

**Table A **

```
lotid |     salesorderdocline | trstype |   trsdate  
------+-----------------------+---------+------------------
111   |     45                | 400     |   10/11/2015  
111   |     0                 | 103     |   15/11/2015  
111   |     65                | 400     |   16/11/2015  
112   |     57                | 133     |   27/08/2015  
112   |     0                 | 103     |   29/08/2015  
113   |     14                | 400     |   24/07/2015
```

**Output**

```
lotid | salesorderdocline  |    trstype  |  trsdate
------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------
112   | 0                  |    103      |  29/08/2015
```

My concern is if the lotid is having trstype as 103 today but tomorrow if it changed to 400 it should not come in the output, if it is changed permanently to 103 than it should show in output

Comment: Which 2 conditions?

Comment: @ydoow did you get my question?

Comment: If you check the lotid 112 after 57 next transaction it gets converted to 0, but for 111 after converting to 0 it again convert to 65 so i don't want to keep that in output

Comment: So are you looking for records with latest `salesorderdocline == 0`? Also it would be better if you can specify the type of sql database.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL-Server, Oracle, MySQL, ... ?

Answer (score 1):

```
with a (
lotid , salesorderdocline ,  trstype,  trsdate) as (
select 111, 45, 400 , ' 10/11/2015' 
union all
 select 111, 0, 103 , ' 15/11/2015' 
 union all
 select 111, 65, 400 , ' 16/11/2015' 
 union all
 select 112, 57, 133, ' 27/08/2015' 
 union all
 select 112, 0, 103 , ' 29/08/2015' 
 union all
 select 113, 14, 400 , ' 24/07/2015' )
 select * from ( select a.*,
   row_number() over (partition by lotid order by trsdate desc) rn 
   from a
  ) TempA
   where rn = 1 and
         salesorderdocline = 0
```

The result is:

```
112 | 0 | 103 | 29/08/2015
```

The `row_number()` assigns numbers starting from 1 for `trsdate` in descending way for each `lotid` group. We are interested only to get the newest record so `rn = 1`.

Instead of `WITH`, use your real table.
I assumed that your DBMS supports `ROW_NUMBER()`.

In case your DBMS doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER()`, it may be generated by:

```
 select a1.lotid , a1.trsdate, count(*) rn
 from a a1
  join a a2 
  on a1.lotid = a2.lotid  and
     a1.trsdate <= a2.trsdate
    group by a1.lotid, a1.trsdate
```